# Visual Studio 2015 turning off function auto-completion

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Community is all of a sudden behaving a little differently with its function completion

Normally I'd start typing for example:

`Void Sta`

At this point Autocomplete kicks in:

[image]

Now when I press enter, what should happen is only the **word** is autocompleted so I would simply end up with `void Start`

However what ends up happening instead is this:

```
private void Start()
{

}
```

I've looked around everywhere in the settings menu and can't find anywhere to disable this. I've tried toggling on and off suggestion/autocomplete modes (Ctrl+Alt+Space), this does not do what I want.

Comment: does your issue is solved or not?

Comment: Hi @Sara-MSFT no unfortunately I can't find it in the Code Snippets Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, this is actually caused by the 'Tools for Unity' addin for Visual Studio. They must have recently updated the tools to include a new feature which does this.

To switch this off, go into the Tools > Options window then expand 'Tools for Unity' and disable Unity Messages code completion

Answer (score 2):

*"Finally figured it out, this is actually caused by the 'Tools for Unity' addin for Visual Studio. They must have recently updated the tools to include a new feature which does this.
To switch this off, go into the Tools > Options window then expand 'Tools for Unity' and disable Unity Messages code completion"*

Didn't work for me - in the same menu, I had to change Unity Messages scope to Default. Now it works. (VS 2017)

Answer (score 0):

This seems a code snippets instead of auto complete. You can try to manage code snippets in the Code Snippets Manager. (I'm not sure that you can disable this snippet.)

Tools\Code Snippets Manager

[image]

Comment: Hey @apr I tried looking through the code snippets manager under CSharp but can't find anything that might be doing it. Also most of the snippets are unremovable anyway as the Remove button is greyed out

Comment: Actually I managed to remove them by removing the folder instead of individual snippets, however after removing every single folder this behaviour is still happening!